# Is it possible to reproject spatial data using SQL Server?

Tags: coordinate-system, sql-server, srid

SQL Server takes an SRID when creating spatial data, but is it possible to retrieve with a different SRID translating the coordinates?

For example, let's say I have a bunch of spatial polygons using SRID 4258, but I'd like to use alongside some pre-existing data that has an SRID of 4326 -- are there built in conversions, or do I have to handle this conversion myself?

The SQL-MM method, which PostGIS implements is [`ST_Transform`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html). How do I do that in SQL Server?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618277/how-do-spatial-reprojection-in-mssql/52618526#52618526

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No.

> **Transform - ability to transform from one spatial ref to another:**
>   No - need 3rd-party tools, Geometry can use any SRID between 0 and 999999. Spatial Tools free CLR add-on does provide limited transform support.

Source: http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=sqlserver2008r2_oracle11gr2_postgis15_compare

Answer (score 10):

Not by default, but check the [SQL Server Spatial Tools](https://github.com/Microsoft/SQLServerSpatialTools) developed by MSDN on GitHub. Specifically, the affine transformation functions.

Comment: +1 I find these tools to be an essential part of Sql Server.

Answer (score 7):

Example for reprojection from EPSG:2193 to EPSG:3857

```
c:\OSGeo4W64\bin\ogr2ogr.exe ^
 -f "MSSQLSpatial"^
 "MSSQL:server=DestServerName;database=DestDbName;trusted_connection=yes"^
 "MSSQL:server=SourceServerName;database=SourceDbName;trusted_connection=yes"^
 -sql "SELECT [Id], [Shape].STAsText() Shape FROM [SourceDbName].[dbo].[SourceTableName]"^
 -nln "DestTableName"^
 -overwrite^
 -s_srs EPSG:2193^
 -t_srs EPSG:3857
```

After this execute SQL Query

```
update  [DestDbName].[dbo].[DestTableName]
set     [ogr_geometry] =  geometry::STGeomFromText([shape], 3857)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and solved in by .Net. I developed a dll in C# and then defined it as a CLR function in MSSQL. Whenever I call this function, this does the conversion for me. Please see this [approach at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44556520/change-projection-in-mssql-for-web-mapping-leaflet-openlayer-openstreetmaps-g?answertab=active#tab-top).
, and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618277/how-do-spatial-reprojection-in-sql-server