# Conversion of X, Y values to different coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, sql-server-spatial

Is there a way to convert coordinate X, Y values in SQL Server from one type of coordinate system to another using SQL Transaction? Like NAD83 State Planes to WGS 1984. My objective is to use a single ArcGIS web map to analyze and show X, Y values that has different type of coordinate system. I plan to convert or transform first the coordinate values to a common type of coordinate system like WGS 1984 before saving them to geodatabase.

Comment: duplicate? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/is-it-possible-to-reproject-spatial-data-using-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to add lat/long fields to sql, then bring them into ArcMap as an X,Y Event projecting them as the state plane they are. Then Calculate Geometry as Decimal Degrees for the new Lat/Long fields.

Another option is just bring in ID, X, Y fields, as an X,Y, define as STateplane, then set Dataframe to 4326 (WGS-84) export the points out using dataframe projection, then bring them back into arcmap, use add X,Y tool, then bring into sql, join, and update.

Answer (score 0):

FME Desktop has a transformer (tool if you want to call it that way) that does exactly what you want to do. It is called AttributeReprojector it reprojects the values without having to create geometries then extracting back the coordinates. You can download a fully functional 14 days demo license. On the other hand if you are using ArcGIS and you have the interoperability extension, which is FME as well you might me able to do the same if the transformer is enabled in the ArcGIS interop extension. FME is avaiable from Safe Software website www.safe.com .
I forgot to add that you can read and write SQL Server directly with FME of course.